# Generating Combinations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Every time I have to do this I "invent" a different way. Time to standardize. I suspect there is some default command I overlooked ready to do this, so I am sorry in advance if the question is too trivial.

What is the better (memory, performance) way to get:

```
 combinations[{1,2,3},2] = {{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}
```

with arbitrary elements in the input list, of course.

Comment: Only trivial if you think to search "subsets". If you, quite reasonably, only think to search "combinations" then, well, you've just done a great service to all such future people by asking this!

Comment: @dreeves Thank you sooo much! Now, if you _really_ want to blame me, look at the third line of code **I** wrote here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815496/plotting-linear-inequalities-in-mathematica/3868677#3868677

Comment: It took me two steps in the help center: combinations => Tuples => Subsets (of course I knew this already, so that may have helped)

Comment: C'mon @Sjoerd, we were talking about _how difficult_ it is. I _almost_ had my self-esteem restored, and you come with that comment :)

Comment: I had to do something to increase my own self-esteem. Mr.Wizard has consistently beaten me in the race to answering questions today. Self-esteem pretty low now.  I have to find a tag of my own or so.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Subsets[{1, 2, 3}, {2}]
```

is the built-in way.

Comment: Damn,I knew it was too trivial :). Thanks!

Comment: cah, congratulations on the Enlightened badge!

Answer (score 7):

Before `Subsets` was added as a core function, the Combinatorica function `KSubsets` was available.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]

KSubsets[{1, 2, 3}, 2]

(*  {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}  *)
```

Combinatorica still provides additional functionality, such as `NextKSubset`:

```
NextKSubset[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}]

(*  {2, 3}  *)
```

This last function can be very helpful for memory management.

Comment: You got to 4000! Congrats ... Now 4010